# Using stat_summary to plot the location of the median

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a way to draw a vertical line where the median occurs for each group in my data on top of a histogram.  I can do that by first grouping by the groups, mutating a new column to be the median, and then faceting by the group.  Here is the some code to do that:

```
library(tidyverse)

N = 1000
m = c(1,5,10)
z = c('A','B','C')

d<-map2_dfr(m,z, ~data.frame(x = rbeta(N,shape1 =.x, shape2 = 20), z = .y))


d %>% 
  group_by(z) %>% 
  mutate(med = median(x)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, fill = z))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins = 10,color = 'black')+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = med))+
  facet_wrap(~z)
```

Since the median is a statistical summary, can I achieve the same result using `stat_summary` or `stat_function` with `geom="vline"`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can; there are just a few tricks to it.

Since `stat_summary` calculates a summary over y for every x, we'll need to fool the function by giving it a dummy x-variable and supply the input for the histogram as y. I've found that giving a dummy-x that is within the range of the data works best, since then it does not affect the axis limits.

In code below, assume `d` is the `d` generated with your code.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, fill = z)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 10, colour = "black") +
  stat_summary(aes(x = 0.1, y = x, xintercept = stat(y), group = z), 
               fun.y = median, geom = "vline") +
  facet_wrap(~ z)
```

[image]

As compared to the original plot:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(z) %>% 
  mutate(med = median(x)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, fill = z))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins = 10,color = 'black')+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = med))+
  facet_wrap(~z)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. It shouldn't be so hard. I would just go with the original approach, it's much clearer.

Comment: I agree. Maybe somebody will have a more straightforward way, but within `stat_summary` this is what I could come up with.

Comment: I set `y=4` and got a point at (median, 4) for each facet with `+ stat_summary(fun = "median", geom = "point")` but got stumped on turning it into a vertical line.

Comment: Surprisingly, this will not work with `rnorm()` instead of `rbeta()`, as the actual values will be far away from 1. Any idea how to correct this?